# Setting Up a Bootsrap 3 Sass version, impossible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

After using Foundation 5 for a few small projects i wanted to switch to the Sass version of Bootstrap 3 but im stuck at the setup and cant find a "How To" on the internet...

i have already downloaded the bootstrap-sass-master, ruby and compass are installed.
Then i used the Ruby Command Prompt with "compass create MyProject".
Then i copied everything from bootstrap-sass-master\vendor\assets into the MyProject folder created by compass.
Then i created a index.html inside that folder with the code from a template from the bootstrap site.
This is how the head looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Basically i followed this two year old example:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-working-with-sass-and-bootstrap--webdesign-9153

But now im stuck because i have no style.css just a screen.css but withthat file it does not work...
My index.html displays without any styles applied.

Can you help me, im sure i did something wrong setting everything up...

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to is to give an access point.

With compass you are gonna compile sass files, and at the end, you will end up with a .css file.

So, lets say your goal is to have a main.css file.

You have to compile it with compass and serve this one. On main.scss, you should import all your bootstrap scss. You need a call to bootstrap.scss and there, this file will take care of import all needed files. (watch routing)

You can control how many of them you need. And always, remember to write your code at the bottom of bootstrap so you can overwrite it.

Take also a look to _variables.scss, the place where you modify bootstrap. Its recommended to create another _variables.scss before import bootstrap, so bootstrap will use your variables instead of the default ones.

Hope it helps.